# JS - Check when a person is speaking

Tags: webkit, web-audio-api

I am trying to figure out how much did a person talk in 1 hour. I tried using this but output always says "not speaking." I tried playing around with the threshold as well. I am struggling with the next steps. Trying to do this client side for privacy reason.

Open to other libraries as well.

```
// Function to check if a person is speaking
function checkSpeaking() {

// Create an audio context
const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
const audioContext = new AudioContext();


// Request microphone access
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then((stream) => {
      // Create an audio source from the microphone stream
      const source = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

      // Create an analyser node
      const analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
      analyser.fftSize = 2048;

      // Connect the source to the analyser
      source.connect(analyser);

      // Start the speech detection loop
      setInterval(() => {
        // Get the frequency data from the analyser
        const bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
        const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

        // Calculate the average volume
        const averageVolume = dataArray.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0) / bufferLength;

        // Adjust the threshold according to your needs
        const threshold = 100;

        // Check if the average volume exceeds the threshold
        const isSpeaking = averageVolume > threshold;

        // Do something with the result
        if (isSpeaking) {
          console.log('Speaking');
        } else {
          console.log('Not speaking');
        }
      }, 100); // Adjust the interval according to your needs
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error accessing microphone:', error);
    });
}

// Call the function to start speech detection
checkSpeaking();
```

Comment: Your code works fine, I tried with various threshold settings.  `Speaking`, `Not speaking`  is printed on console